# Zookeeper Queue with Lock

Tags: distribution, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

As we see in Java Linked Blocking Queue, take() method takes lock/gaurds the tail node before dequeueing from queue. So no 2 threads will take the same node from the tail. In case of zookeeper, all the process watching the root node of queue will get notified and all of them can grab the same set of nodes and start processing the same nodes.

So how can I call this a distributed queue then. I am talking of the producer consumer reciepe of Zookeeper. http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.1/zookeeperTutorial.html#sc_producerConsumerQueues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example code, when consuming the code does,

```
zk.delete(root + "/element" + min, 0);
```

Only 1 node will successfully perform the deletion, every other process which attempts the delete will throw an error, so the consumer knows that he is the only one to consume that element.